# Protecting questions with problematic opinion-based answers?

Tags: discussion

Should we protect [Are there any privacy issues regarding publishing the image of a grave marker online?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/101/1006)

It seems to be attracting answers which are based on opinion, where the newer answers are simply offering opinions without any substantial discussion of the ethics involved, or links to references where the ethics have been discussed.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely!

Protecting questions only prevents answers by anonymous and very new users (which is exactly the group causing the problem in this case).